# SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader() returning no rows

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm trying to read data from a table in my Sqlite database using the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite classes in a UWP application.

There's a single row in the table, inserted by the same application. I can see the data using a Sqlite database browser, and can copy-paste the SQL query into the database browser, run it, and see the correct result returned.

However, when I run the same query using the code below, no data is returned.

```
string _query = "SELECT [Source] FROM [Sessions] ORDER BY [MinTimeOffset];";

_SessionList = new List<string>();

using (SqliteCommand _command = new SqliteCommand(_query, _Connection))
{
    using (SqliteDataReader _reader = _command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (_reader.Read())
        {
            _SessionList.Add((string)_reader["Source"]);
        }
    }
}
```

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Sessions (
    [Id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    [Source] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    [MinValue] FLOAT NULL, 
    [MaxValue] FLOAT NULL, 
    [MinTimeOffset] BIGINT NULL, 
    [MaxTimeOffset] BIGINT NULL
)
```

And the data is:

```
1, "2017-09-17-070007-ELEMNT BOLT BDA2-15-0.fit", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

No exceptions are thrown, `_reader.Read()` returns `false` the first time it is called, and `_reader.HasRows` is `false`, suggesting no data is returned by the query.

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing here - what could cause this?

**Update following comments:**
 I can use `ExecuteScalar()` to retrieve data from the same table without a problem, although this is performed as part of a transaction alongside thousands of inserts, so I guess is slightly different. The code for that, which works, is as follows:

```
    _query = "SELECT [Id] FROM Sessions WHERE [Source] = @sessionName LIMIT 1;";
    long _sessionId;
    _IngestCommand.CommandText = _query;
    _IngestCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@sessionName", sessionName));
    _sessionId = (long)_IngestCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Regarding how I connection, the database is either a new database created from scratch via DDL statements, or an existing version created in the same manner. It makes no difference which of those two methods I use. There's only one database file at any time - I'm deleting the folder contents manually before running to be sure I'm not opening any copies or old versions etc, then creating the database programmatically and inserting a bunch of data into it in a transaction, including a record into this table which is successfully retrieved as part of the insert logic, then committing the transaction.

At this point I can browse all of the inserted data in a Sqlite database browser. Then I'm calling the method which includes the `ExecuteReader()` code shown above and receiving no results. The same connection is used throughout - it's opened in a class constructor and closed in the Dispose() method of that class (I know that's not great design - I'm going to refactor it once I've got this figured out. The connection code is shown below:

```
var _connSB = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Cache = SqliteCacheMode.Private,
    DataSource = filename,
    Mode = SqliteOpenMode.ReadWriteCreate
};

_Connection = new SqliteConnection(_connSB.ToString());
_Connection.Open();
```

And the code that builds the database:

```
string[] _commands = {
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProjectMetaData ([Id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, [Value] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Series ([Id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, [Unit] NVARCHAR(48) NOT NULL, [MinValue] FLOAT NULL, [MaxValue] FLOAT NULL, [MinTimeOffset] BIGINT NULL, [MaxTimeOffset] BIGINT FLOAT NULL)",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sessions ([Id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [Source] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, [MinValue] FLOAT NULL, [MaxValue] FLOAT NULL, [MinTimeOffset] BIGINT NULL, [MaxTimeOffset] BIGINT NULL)",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data ([Id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [SeriesId] INT NOT NULL, [SessionId] NOT NULL, [TimeOffset] BIGINT NOT NULL, [Value] FLOAT NOT NULL, [Discounted] BIT NULL)"
};

foreach (string _command in _commands)
{
    using (SqliteCommand _dbCommand = new SqliteCommand(_command, _Connection))
    {
        _dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you run a simple query `SELECT * FROM Sessions` only?

Comment: @MartinZikmund the same happens, no results returned. I can retrieve data using the `ExecuteScalar()` method without any issues though, including from that table

Comment: Can you show us also your scalar query that works and the return value you get back?

Comment: Could you show us how you connect to the database? Isn't it possible that you actually connect to an empty instance of the DB? Could you check the AppData folder of your app?

Comment: @MattGibson I've updated the question with the ExecuteScalar code. The return value is the `Id` - 1

Comment: I ended up going ahead with the refactor to take my mind off it for a little bit, and all of a sudden it works. I'm guessing there was something funky in there that I couldn't see that's been solved with the refactor. What a pain. Oh well, thanks for the help guys!